# c# search collection by field in base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, observablecollection

Given is a base class and some derived classes:

```
class baseVehicle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string vName { get; set; }
    public int maxSpeed { get; set; }
}
class truck : baseVehicle
{
    public int loadTons { get; set; }
}
class cabrio : baseVehicle
{
    public bool softTop { get; set; }
}
class suv : baseVehicle
{
    public int NoOfSeats { get; set; }
}
```

and all these vehicle objects are created and inserted into a collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<object> vehicles = new ObservableCollection<object>vehicles();
```

What is the most efficient way to find the vehicle with vName = "Alfa Romeo Giulietta" or with Id = 43?

Comment: Use `ObservableCollection<baseVehicle>` instead of `ObservableCollection<object>`. You can search the collection via LINQ: `vehicles.Where(v=>Id=123);`

Comment: Why not make the Collection of type `baseVehicle` and then use `vehicles.FirstOrDefault(v => v.vName == "Alfa Romeo Giulietta" || v.Id == 32);`?

Comment: OOps, but the collection would contain trucks, cabrios, etc...?

Comment: @pb_SKAT As long as the objects stored in the collection derive from the same base class it still works. Take a look at Polymorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your collection to `ObservableCollection<baseVehicle>` OR you can cast it like this:

```
vehicles.Cast<baseVehicle>().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 43 || i.vName == "Name...");
```

Comment: @Iwb: thanks, good idea to cast collection, this may address my concerns that I not only have to find a particular vehicle but then to deal with it based on its derived class. I.e. if the vehicle found is a truck I need to get a class-truck object.

Comment: You can work with Interfaces as well. :).
If you problem was solved, please accept the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should create collection of `baseVehicle` (`baseVehicle` is base class for others and you can add every object which has type of `baseVehicle` or type derived from `baseVehicle`), not collection of `object` (you can use collection of `object` but you should cast elements to correct type):

```
public ObservableCollection<baseVehicle> vehicles = new ObservableCollection<baseVehicle>vehicles();
```

**TO GET ONE ELEMENT:**

You can use `FirstOrDefault()`- you can use `First()` but you should be sure that element exists in collection (with condition in lambda):

```
var vehicle = vehicles.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 43);
if (vehicle != null)
{
    //some code
}
```

You can combine conditions using `OR`:

```
var vehicle = vehicles.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 43 || i.vName == "some name");
```

Also, you can use `AND`:

```
var vehicle = vehicles.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 43 && i.vName == "some name");
```

**TO GET SEVERAL ELEMENTS:**

Use `Where()`;

```
var someVehicles = vehicles.Where(i => i.Contains("Alfa"));
//or
var someVehicles = vehicles.Where(i => i.Id == 2 || i.vName == "Some name);
```

Comment: cheers, works perfect. I am coming from VB thinks look a bit different there... But will I be able to deal with the found object as e.g. a SUV?

Comment: @pb_SKAT, you are welcome, accept the correct and working answer please

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, use `ObservableCollection<baseVehicle>` and filter on it:

```
collection.where(x=>x.Id == 43 || x.vName == "Alfa Romeo Giulietta").FirstOrDefault();
```